# replicate values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the bellow df and I'm trying to replicate the single value present in the column(Per_Extract) in the rest of the column
df

```
    IN          Per_Extract                                 
0   IN7395593   NaN 
1   IN7444113   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20   
2   IN7444613   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20   
3   IN7444116   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20   
4   IN7334213   NaN
```

my desired output should be this:

```
df
    IN          Per_Extract                                 
0   IN7395593   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20   
1   IN7444113   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20   
2   IN7444613   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20   
3   IN7444116   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20   
4   IN7334213   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
```

I tried ffill, but it didnt work

```
df['Per_Extract'] = df['Per_Extract'].ffill()
```

coud you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#replace NaN text with np.nan
# ffill and bfill null values
# Strip Per_extract with whitespaces, if present, they fail replace

df['Per_Extract']=df['Per_Extract'].str.strip().replace('NaN', np.nan).ffill().bfill()
df
```

```
IN  Per_Extract
0   0   IN7395593   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
1   1   IN7444113   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
2   2   IN7444613   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
3   3   IN7444116   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
4   4   IN7334213   FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try:

```
df['Per_Extract'] = df['Per_Extract'].fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
df
          IN                        Per_Extract
0  IN7395593  FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
1  IN7444113  FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
2  IN7444613  FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
3  IN7444116  FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
4  IN7334213  FROM : 2022-08-01 TO : 2022-10-20
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the follwowing syntax

```py
df['Per_Extract'] = df['Per_Extract'].fillna(method='ffill')
```